# Convert Canvas to audio in Browser for datamoshing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to do some datamoshing in the browser and would like to load the ImageData from a Canvas into AudioData, so I can use some audio libraries (like tuna) to add effects on the Data.

This is what I have tried so far

```
const canvasToBlob = (canvas) => {
  let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  return dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);
};

const dataURItoBlob = (dataURI) => {
  // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
  // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
  let byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

  // separate out the mime component
  let mime = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
  console.log(mime);

  // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
  let ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  let ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  };

  // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
  let blob = new Blob([ab], {type: 'audio/wav'});
  return blob;
};

export default function audioConvert (canvas) {
  const imageBlob = canvasToBlob(canvas);
  let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  let fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onloadend = () => {
    console.log(fileReader.result);
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(fileReader.result).then((decodedData) => {
      console.log(decodedData);
    });
  };
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(imageBlob);
};
```

Unfortunately I only get the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
```

How could I change my code to get an AudioContext.

Or is an AudioContext even the correct way?

Some effects that I would like to add to the Image are 'Echoing', or 'Wah-Wah' as found f.e. in Audacity.

Comment: Going through file formats is just making needless work. Use the Audio context to create sound buffers then move the image data into the sound buffer. The sound buffer data is a float within -1,to 1 while image data is bytes,RGBA 0-255. How you transform between the two is up to you but a direct dump will just be peeking out crackles (if any there is any sound at all)  Do something like sound channels from RGB as left = ((R/128)-1 + (G/128)-1)/2 and right = ((B/128)-1 + G/128)-1)/2 has red left blue rigth and green in the middle. options are endless

Comment: kudos to @Blindman67's comment, just [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) to help you create AudioBuffer, once you'll have determined how you'll normalize your image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Image to Canvas to Audio context soundbuffer example

No answer yet so I have just added a very quick load image and convert to soundbuffer and play.

```js
// Stereo
var log = (data)=>console.log(data);
var audioCtx = new AudioContext(); // get audio context
var pixelPlayTime,sBuffers,ctx,can,startTime,source;  // sBuffers is the wav form array
// load image
var image = new Image;
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Hoverfly07.jpg";

// when loaded convert to wave
image.onload = function(){
    displayit.innerHTML = "";

    // create a canvas to read pixel data
    can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width = this.width;
    can.height = this.height;
    ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);
    var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height).data;

    // get image size and workout sound buffer sizes
    var pixelCount = this.width * this.height;
    pixelPlayTime = pixelCount / audioCtx.sampleRate;
    sBuffers = audioCtx.createBuffer(2, pixelCount, audioCtx.sampleRate);

    // left gets red full vol and blue half
    var channel1 = sBuffers.getChannelData(0); // get channel 0
    var i = 0;
    while(i < pixelCount){
        // get red and some of green for this channel
        var sample = ((data[i*4]/128) - 1 + (data[i*4+2]/255) - 0.5) / 1.5;
        channel1[i] = sample < -1 ? -1 : sample > 1 ? 1 : sample;
        i ++
    }

    // Right gets green full vol and blue half
    var channel2 = sBuffers.getChannelData(1); // get channel 1
    i = 0;
    while(i < pixelCount){
        // get blue and some of green for this channel
        var sample = ((data[i*4 + 1]/128) - 1 + (data[i*4+2]/255) - 0.5) / 1.5;
        channel2[i] = sample < -1 ? -1 : sample > 1 ? 1 : sample;
        i ++
    }

    // sound buffers created prep to play
    source = audioCtx.createBufferSource(); // for playing the buffer
    source.buffer = sBuffers;              // point to the buffer
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);       // connect

    // show image as canvas
    can.style.width = Math.floor(this.width / 4) + "px"
    can.style.height = Math.floor(this.height / 4) + "px"
    displayit.innerHTML = "Click image to hear it<br>";
    displayit.appendChild(can);

    // Wait for clien click
    can.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      requestAnimationFrame(startSounds);
     });

}
// start playing the sount
function startSounds(time){
    if(startTime === undefined){
      startTime = time;
      pixelPlayTime *= 1000; // convert from seconds to micro seconds
      source.start();                             // and play dat phunky fly
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    }
}

// display where the sound data is on the image.
// Basic timing use to show at what line the sound is being generated from.
function update(time){
    var pos = (time - startTime) / pixelPlayTime;
    var posY = Math.floor(pos * can.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    ctx.fillRect(0,posY,can.width,4);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,posY-4,can.width,4,0,posY-4,can.width,4);
    if(pos < 1){
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="displayit" style="font-family:arial"><h2>Please wait loading image</h2></div>

<div style="font-family:arial">
<b><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Fir0002"  title="en:User:Fir0002">fir0002</a> | <a  href="http://www.flagstaffotos.com.au">flagstaffotos.com.au</a></b>



Image attribution
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td style="width:90px;"><img alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/CC_some_rights_reserved.svg/90px-CC_some_rights_reserved.svg.png" width="90" height="36" srcset="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/CC_some_rights_reserved.svg/135px-CC_some_rights_reserved.svg.png 1.5x, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/CC_some_rights_reserved.svg/180px-CC_some_rights_reserved.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="744" data-file-height="300"></td>
<td><span xml:lang="en"><i>This file is published under the following <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons" title="w:Creative Commons">Creative Commons</a> license:<br>
<a href="//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/">Attribution <b>NonCommercial</b> Unported 3.0</a></i></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<div style="font-family:arial">
```